# How to exit vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

How to exit .vim script file? I want something like this in my init.vim

```
if exists('g:vscode')
  "Do not execute rest of init.vim, do not apply any configs
  exit
endif

"...some configs...
```

Google only searchs exiting from Vim itself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's precisely what the Ex command `finish` is used for.

```
if exists('g:vscode')
  "Do not execute rest of init.vim, do not apply any configs
  finish
endif
```

It terminates sourcing of a script file. See [`:h :finish`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:finish).